# How can I make my plugins work in a location other than "vendor" in Rails 3.2.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I followed some instructions, which I'm unable to locate again, to move my plugins to the "lib" directory.

So I have this structure now:

```
/lib
/lib/plugins
/lib/plugins/plugin1
/lib/plugins/plugin1/lib
/lib/plugins/plugin1/lib/plugin1.rb
```

I had tried this in my `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/lib/plugins)
```

But that isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Trashing the `plugins` part of the path and putting the plugins directory directly in doesn't work either. Each plugin has an `init.rb` file that basically requires the main library, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if [these are the instructions you were following](http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins), but you probably want the plugin folder itself at the root of `lib`:

```
/lib
/lib/plugin1
/lib/plugin1/plugin1.rb
```

You also may need an initializer: `config/initializers/plugin1.rb`.

If that doesn't help, please post more information about what you're expecting to see and why it's not working.